# Detect Printer in Excel Workbook.BeforePrint Event

Tags: vb.net, excel, events, vba

When handling the Workbook.BeforePrint event in Excel, is there any way to determine the printer that's being targeted? I know the event handler signature allows cancelling of the event, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195836.aspx), but I'd like to cancel all print events unless the printer is a PDF printer.

The edge case that I've found that if a user chooses "Save As" or "Export" to create a PDF, it uses the PDF printer driver to perform the save or export and triggers the event handler, but doesn't update which printer is set as the application's active printer when doing so. Is there a different way to detect the targeted printer?

Answer (score 0):

**VBA-Excel**

```
Debug.Print Application.ActivePrinter
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great for all the normal cases but isn't covering a couple other ways to create PDFs. I've expanded my question to be a little clearer.

Comment: You can trap the `Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` and by default set the relevant pdf printer? And once the save is done, restore it to the original printer? If the user is doing a normal save then changing the default printer will not have any effect.

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm finding that if you export to PDF instead of save to PDF, the Workbook_BeforeSave never triggers, so you don't get the opportunity to set the printer. Do you know of a way to detect exporting?

Comment: Are you referring to `expression.ExportAsFixedFormat()` method?

Comment: Essentially, but done through the UI, not programmatically. Choosing File->Export->Create PDF/XPS Document in Office 2013 or File->Save & Send->Create PDF/XPS Document in Office 2010 is the last option that I'm looking to handle.

Comment: In such a case if you want to trap all possible scenarios then simply set the activeprinter in `Workbook_Open()` and reset it on `Workbook_BeforeClose`?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
Private mbSaving As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    mbSaving = False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    If InStr(1, Application.ActivePrinter, "PDF") = 0 And Not mbSaving Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

    mbSaving = False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    mbSaving = True

End Sub
```

The Workbook_AfterSave doesn't fire on saving as a PDF. It's a strange order of events, I think.

Comment: This is so close. Workbook_AfterSave doesn't fire with saving as a PDF, but Workbook_BeforePrint does, so it gives me a detectable event and what you've posted works great for that. The one scenario that it doesn't handle is if you choose Export in order to create the PDF. This will catch in the Workbook_BeforePrint handler but not either of the save handlers. Is there a way to detect exporting? I haven't found one yet.

Comment: How do you export? I didn't see anything on the Ribbon for that.

Comment: File->Export->Create PDF/XPS Document in Office 2013 or File->Save & Send->Create PDF/XPS Document in Office 2010.

Comment: That's a tough one. Working on it.

Comment: I'm stumped. I don't think there's an event for that. You may be left repurposing the ribbon control.  http://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/2012/10/01/backstage-wordvba/